# Cleaning commit history for selected files in large forked GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a large forked git repo where I've made changes in several files and created several new files (mostly, but not entirely, in libraries).

Before I initially publish, I'd like to remove all previous commit history  from the files I created, and ideally from the already existing files I changed, without affecting any other aspects of the repo. I want these changes to apply both to my local and GitHub copies of the repo. I've seen a range of discussions re commit history but none seem to cover this case in a safe manner.

Thanks very much!

Comment: What have you done, please? Where is your repo?

Comment: Read about squashing commits - it might be good way, if you want less commits

Comment: I haven't done anything in this regard yet. The repo needs to stay private for the moment until it's cleaned up.

Comment: Regarding getting less commits, since I'm the only one who will be making commits on this fork, I'm not overly concerned about that aspect in this particular case.